# Building a SELinux image - RPM Package compilation Error

Tags: linux, rpm, yocto, selinux, libselinux

I've enabled the SELinux by doing the below changes,

1. Added meta-selinux path to BUILDDIR/conf/bblayers.conf file.
2. Set DISTRO_FEATURES_append=" pam selinux" in in BUILDDIR/conf/local.conf file.

I've executed the below command to generate a default se-Linux image,

```
$ bitbake core-image-selinux
```

And getting an error from RPM Package,

```
**../../rpm-5.4.15/rpmio/macro.c: In function 'expandMacro':
../../rpm-5.4.15/rpmio/macro.c:2309:15: error: '_globalI' undeclared (first use in this function)
   rpmsm sm = (_globalI ? NULL
               ^~~~~~~~**
```

for the time being, I override the error by removing the **inherit with-selinux** from `selinux/recipes-devtools/rpm/rpm_selinux.inc`.

Couldn't find a similar issue in google or issue reported.
Could you please someone explain to me, how to debug this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can post the relevant output from `grep -IR -B 1 -A 1 _global`? If you are lucky you will find a `#define _globalI ...` and the proceeding line will be the guard.

Comment: Configure rpm using --without-sepol --without-semanage is the first thing to try.

Comment: @jww No _globalI macro definition in the source code. I already started digging into source code and env variables to understand from where this definition is coming at compilation time.

Comment: @JeffJohnson Yes.RPM package is configured --with-sepol --with-semanage at configuration time. So, let me try --without-sepol --without-semanage. Thank You mate.

Comment: _globalI would hold a "global interpreter" for an embedded application, and is used by two unfinished embedded wrappers onto additional functionality provided by SELinux. Only --with-libselinux is needed for RPM+SELINUX functionality. Note that SELinux has moved to loadable modules in RPM4.